# Obtener el máximo valor de un grupo y asignarle solo a la primera fila - SQL SErver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día con todos,

Estoy intentando que mi consulta a una tabla muestre una columna adicional, en la que obtenga el valor máximo de la columna "valor1" y según la columna "grupo" y ese valor obtenido solo esté en el primer registro de ese grupo el resto debe estar en cero.

Entiendo que tiene que ser con Over Partition pero no lo logro.

[image: La columna en amarrillo es lo que se requiere]

Answer (score 0):

Para ello no solamente requieres del uso de los `over()...`, tienes que hacer uso de una columna auxiliar para saber cuál es la primera fila particionada por grupo.

Lo primero, simular tu tabla y almacenarla en una temporal:

```sql
select *
into #temporal
from (values ('AAA', 18),
             ('AAA', 18),
             ('AAA', 18),
             ('BBB', 25),
             ('BBB', 25),
             ('CCC', 13),
             ('CCC', 13),
             ('CCC', 13),
             ('CCC', 13)) x(grupo, valor1)
```

Quedando algo así:

```sql
+-----+------+
|grupo|valor1|
+-----+------+
|AAA  |18    |
|AAA  |18    |
|AAA  |18    |
|BBB  |25    |
|BBB  |25    |
|CCC  |13    |
|CCC  |13    |
|CCC  |13    |
|CCC  |13    |
+-----+------+
```

Lo último es realizar un script como el siguiente:

```sql
select case when x.enumerado = 1 then x.maximo else 0 end maximoFormat,
       x.grupo,
       x.valor1
from (select row_number() over (partition by grupo order by grupo) enumerado,
             max(valor1) over (partition by grupo order by grupo)  maximo,
             grupo,
             valor1
      from #temporal) x
```

El `row_number()` sirve para saber cuál es la fila 1 por cada grupo, después el `max()` es saber cuál es el máximo valor por cada grupo usando la columna `valor1`. Por último, colocamos todo en una subquery y realizas un `case...when` para coloca el valor máximo solo en las primeras filas de cada grupo.

La salida final quedaría:

```sql
+------------+-----+------+
|maximoFormat|grupo|valor1|
+------------+-----+------+
|18          |AAA  |18    |
|0           |AAA  |18    |
|0           |AAA  |18    |
|25          |BBB  |25    |
|0           |BBB  |25    |
|13          |CCC  |13    |
|0           |CCC  |13    |
|0           |CCC  |13    |
|0           |CCC  |13    |
+------------+-----+------+
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

> <kbd>**[Ver Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J4Lvr_aL)**</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta!, algo así lo estaba planteado, sin embargo creí que talvez habría alguna forma mas corta.
Me siento tonto!!, toda mi vida haciendo **select ('AAA' grupo,18 valor1) union all select('AAA',18)...** y ahora veo que hay una forma mas corta.

Gracias, eres un crack!!

Comment: Hola! bueno, básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es colocar toda tu query actual como subquery y agregar ese `row_number` con `max`, la verdad es que no veo que la solución sea extensa.